# display the scores

Tags: python, sorting

I am a newbie in Python progaram I am trying to implement a program wherein it will sort the text below from highest to lowest

```
scores={}
highest_score=0.0
highest=''
lowest_score=100.0
lowest=''
average=0.0
sums=0.0
```

Comment: Not clear what your expected output would have been, could you write it?

Comment: You'll need to sort you dictionary based on the value.

Comment: @KindStranger Also, you don't sort a dictionary... You make a sorted list which represents the original dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will split the names from the text into a list of `[name, score]`. You can then sort that list based on the second entry of each `[name, score]` list using the [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function:

```
scores = [i.split('-') for i in score_text]
scores = [[i[0], float(i[1])] for i in scores]
scores = sorted(scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Note: `sorted` by default sorts from lowest to highest, with `reverse=True` sorting will be from highest to lowest. To get the desired output, first get the max and min values:

```
max_score = max([i[1] for i in scores])
min_score = min([i[1] for i in scores])
```

And then iterate through the sorted `[name, score]` pairs printing in the correct format if the score is max, min or otherwise:

```
for i in scores:
    if i[1] == max_score:
        print 'highest score: {}  of {}'.format(i[1], i[0])
        pass

    if i[1] not in [max_score, min_score]:
        print 'score: {} of {}'.format(i[1], i[0])
        pass

    if i[1] == min_score:
        print 'lowest score: {}  of {}'.format(i[1], i[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the entries like this:

```
lowest_score = min(scores.values())
lowest = [key for key, value in scores.items() if value == lowest_score]

highest_score = max(scores.values())
highest = [key for key, value in scores.items() if value == highest_score]
```

Keep in mind that comparing floats for equality might not work. You might instead have to check if the absolute difference is smaller than a very small value.

Answer (score 0):

finding the key first is better, performance wise, since querying the value would be done in constant time.

```
lowest_key = min(scores.keys(), key=scores.__getitem__)
highest_key = max(scores.keys(), key=scores.__getitem__)
lowest_value = scores[lowest_key]
highest_value = scores[highest_key]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two lists:

- one with highest score
- one with lowest score

for key, value in score.items():

```
    if float(value) < lowest_score:
        lowest_score = [float(value)]
        lowest = [key]
    if float(value)=lowest_score:
        lowest_score += [float(value)]
        lowest += [key]

    if float(value) > highest_score:
        highest_score=float(value)
        highest=key  
    if float(value) = highest_score:
        lowest_score += [float(value)]
        lowest += [key]
```

And just print lists with a for:

```
print "highest score:"
for i in range(lenght(highest_score)) :
    print highest_score[i]," of ",highest[i]

print "lowest score:"
for i in range(lenght(lowest_score)) :
    print lowest_score[i]," of ",lowest[i]
```

Comment: whenever i use len it has an error for i in range(len(highest_score)) :
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()